# Non-decreasing function in $f:A\rightarrow B$

Tags: functions

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function where set A contains 4 elements and set B contains 3 elements.
Then find the total number of non-decreasing functions.

As per the book the solution is "Number of non decreasing function is equal to number of non negative integral solutions of equation x + y + z =  4" which is $^6C_2=15$. I am not able to understand it , can some one provide me more lucid answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ with $a_1<a_2<a_3<a_4$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ with $b_1\lt b_2\lt b_3$. Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the number of pre-images of each of the three elements in $B$ (respectively) under a map $f:A\rightarrow B$, that is, $\vert f^{-1}(\{b_i\})\vert=x_i$. Then, we certainly have
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=4\:\text{ with }\:x_1,x_2,x_3\geqslant0$$

There are $15$ solutions to the above equation in non-negative integers as the OP has mentioned. It is clear that each solution gives rise to a certain number of desired functions (we haven't fixed the values of the function yet). But, with the additional constraint that we want only non-decreasing functions, with each of the $15$ solutions, we can associate precisely $1$ function that satisfies the requirements of the problem.

To see this, let us take a solution $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, and let $f$ be a function with $\vert f^{-1}(\{b_i\})\vert=y_i$. Since we want non-decreasing maps $f:A\rightarrow B$, we must have the following:
$$ f(a_i)=
\begin{cases}
b_1,  & \text{if $0\lt i \leqslant y_1$} \\
b_2, & \text{if $y_1\lt i \leqslant y_1+y_2$} \\
b_3, & \text{if $y_1+y_2 \lt i \leqslant 4$}
\end{cases}$$

Since this fixes the values of $f$, there is precisely one function with the required properties associated with each of the solutions to the aforementioned equation.

So, indeed, there are $\boxed{15}$ such functions.